# Number of markers in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm wondering if there's a way to show the number of markers you have in a sequence in the blender VSE? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run this code in the Text Editor:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
print("Number of markers: "+str(len(scene.timeline_markers)))
```

And in Menu > Window > Toggle System Console see the result.
[image]